# will open() system call block on remote filesystem?

Tags: c, linux

I would like to know if the open() system call in Linux latest kernel would block if the filesystem is mounted as remote device, for example a CEPH filesystem, or NFS , and there is a network failure of some sort?

Comment: obviously it will block. Check out this link it may helpful i think.http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. How long depends on the speed (and state) of the uplink, but your process or thread will block until the remote operation finishes. NFS is a bit notorious for this, and some FUSE file systems handle the blocking for whatever has the file handle, but you will block on `open()`, `read()` and `write()`, often at the mercy of the network and the other system.

Don't use `O_NONBLOCK` to get around it, or you're potentially reading from or writing to a black hole (which would just block anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an `open()` call can block when trying to open a file on a remote file system if there is a network failure of some sort.

Depending on how the remote file system is mounted, it may just take a long time (multiple seconds) to determine that the remote file system is unavailable and return unsuccessfully after what seems like an inordinate amount of time, or it may simply lock up indefinitely until the remote resource becomes available once more (or until the mapping is removed from the system).

Comment: Huh. The iOS app said this was unanswered when I answered it, but the time on your answer states clearly otherwise. A bug reporting I go! (Leaving this comment to clearly point it out, sorry for the noise). There were no answers, according to it.

Comment: @TimPost: I had a vaguely problem with another question where extra comments to my answer didn't show up timely in the iOS app, so I responded via the app a little differently than I would have done had I seen the extra comments.

Comment: yes , but O_NONBLOCK flag is made precisely to do not block the call, how does the kernel makes it work if the volume is not available, but the file name has already been accepted by the open() and success status returned?

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities (but O_NONBLOCK is new to this discussion — I also have another recent answer where O_NONBLOCK figures, so I was surprised when this turned up here). First, the `open()` itself may block, even with the O_NONBLOCK flag to be set on the file descriptor; it cannot return successfully until it is assured that the remote file access is permitted.  It might be able to fail quicker, but it cannot succeed.  The main time O_NONBLOCK comes into play is with `read()` and `write()` or their relatives. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ A `read()` might return indicating that there is no data available to read.  I'm not sure that `write()` can return except with a status such as 0 bytes written because the call would block waiting for network availability.  It would need very careful scrutiny of the manual pages to determine it.  But my expectation is that `open()` — the subject of the question — might take time to respond successfully if there are network problems to the remote file system.  It might fail faster, but it cannot succeed fast unless everything is working smoothly.

Comment: @Nulik `O_NONBLOCK` is designed to allow fast return from `open()` when you _know_ the call will block for a determined amount of time, the best example I can offer is opening a modem or serial device that needs a second or two to initialize. But there, you're writing a _protocol_, not data that should persist. You _want_ `open()` to hang on busy I/O, otherwise you can't trust the handle it returns.

Comment: @TimPost, could you maybe explain more (or point to info about) what happens when you use a nonblocking open for a resource you know might take a while, and what that accomplishes?