# Call to open(2) apparently blocks indefinitely

Tags: linux, io, i2c

I'm debugging some third-party code for an embedded Linux instrumentation solution (it's proprietary code, so unfortunately I can't share it here). The actual code is written in Python, and the Python module in question is implemented natively in C.

Based on my debugging results so far, I am fairly convinced than an [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) call to open a [`/dev/i2c`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface) device is blocking indefinitely. As all interesting bugs do, this only happens occasionally, but poses a big problem when it does (as it makes the entire system come to a halt).

I've tried to get a better understanding of the circumstances under which open(2) might block. The documentation for the `O_NONBLOCK` flag states that "... *this flag has no effect for regular files and block devices; that is, I/O operations will (briefly) block when device activity is required, regardless of whether `O_NONBLOCK` is set.*" The C code for the Python module does *not* specify `O_NONBLOCK`, and my understanding is that `/dev/i2c` is a character device and not a block device, so maybe specifying `O_NONBLOCK` might help in this situation?

I also understand that open(2) can block, for example, [when opening a file on a remote file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869815/will-open-system-call-block-on-remote-filesystem), but I'd like to know under what circumstances this can be expected when opening a device file. One other suspicion I have is that the system might be temporarily running out of file handles due to other activities that are going on at the same time. Would this result in open(2) blocking until some file handles are released? Or do I need to dig into the actual `/dev/i2c` device driver to further diagnose this?

Comment: This is all dependent on the specific device driver. If its `open` operation blocks, it will block.

Comment: Possibly some process already has the device open. Use lsof to check.